# First 10 digits after decimal point in the number $(1+\sqrt{3})^{2015}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, irrational-numbers

**The question** is how to find first 10 digits after decimal point in the number $(1+\sqrt{3})^{2015}$.

I keep running into this kind of problems in a context of symmetric polynomials.

Comment: no calculator can be used, i suppose...

Comment: @Blex I'm not so certain it would help very much to use a calculator.

Comment: @Blex, i have a feeling that this is some kind of classical problem. I guess we can use a standard calculator. With help of WolframAlpha we can see that all ten digits are actually zeros.

Comment: Consider $$ (1-\sqrt{3})^{2015} $$

Comment: Indeed and you just got the classic answer.

Comment: Hint: $(1 + \sqrt{3})^{2015} + (1 - \sqrt{3})^{2015}$ is an integer since every other term in the binomial expansion cancels...

Comment: To close voters: it is not a question about simple calculation, but about using mathematical methods (see the answer and comments).

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/computation-without-a-computer was posted before this - the solutions there might also be useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint:  (i) The number $(1+\sqrt{3})^{2015}+(1-\sqrt{3})^{2015}$  is an integer. We can see this by *imagining* expanding using the Binomial Theorem. Terms involving odd powers of $\sqrt{3}$ cancel.

(ii) The number $(1-\sqrt{3})^{2015}$ is extremely small in absolute value, and negative. So $(1+\sqrt{3})^{2015}$ is nearly an integer.

Comment: Wow, that is really cool, thank you. And no symmetric polynomials...

Comment: You are welcome.  Here we used conjugates. Whenever $1+\sqrt{3}$ has a problem, its conjugate $1-\sqrt{3}$ is ready to help.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see that $u_n=(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n$ is an integer is to exhibit a simple three-term recursion for it.
$$
u_{n+1} = 2u_n+u_{n-1}
$$